# Arch linux Gnome Черный экран и стрелка курсора

Tags: linux, archlinux, gnome

Как и многие начинал в свое время знакомство с ПК с замечательной ос - Windows xp.
Сейчас по мере движения вперед (меня) и движения куда-то в непонятную сторону (Windows) назрела ситуация перехода на что то менее мозгодробительное.

Поставил рядом с win Ubuntu gnome 16.04 , потом Ubuntu 17,10. Начал смотреть на Arch Linux (хочется разобраться, + понравился) но ломать то что сейчас стоит на пк не стал, вместо этого решил потренироваться на VirtualBox, так как установка в текстовом режиме и прочее.(хотя не нашел ее сложной, но не об этом)

После установки оси и дров на видюху виртуалки ставлю gdm и gnome и они устанавливаются, но после перезапуска системы я наблюдаю черный экран с курсором gdm (стрелка мыши). Нашел графический инсталлятор для Arch, из 6 попыток на виртуалках (делать все 6 раз одно и то же) на 2 все работает как положено а на оставшихся 4-х - черный экран и мышь.
Ошибка появляется (читай пропадает) не системно, то есть от чего на 2 из 6 виртуалок оно работает я не могу понять.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Опытным путем выяснил что виноват не Gnome в целом а только лишь Gdm, 4 виртуалки похожие одна на одну но не GDM а default менеджер - работают все 4. В чем причина данного сбоя? как это исправить? будет ли такое на реальном железе ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось установкой `virtualbox-guest-modules-arch`

[Тут подсказали](http://archlinux.org.ru/forum/post/197263/)